# What is the difference between layout gravity and gravity in android?

Tags: android, android-layout

I always struggled when and where to use layout_gravity and gravity. Pleaae help me

Answer (score 1):

Easy trick to remember: Take "layout-gravity" as "Lay-outside-gravity"

Their names should help you:

1. android:gravity sets the gravity of the content of the View its used
   on.
2. android:layout_gravity sets the gravity of the View or Layout in its parent.

And an example is [here](https://thinkandroid.wordpress.com/2010/01/14/how-to-position-views-properly-in-layouts/).